# Integration flow accessing a paged http resource

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to consume entirely a paged resource as follow, however my aproach is raising a StackOverflowException.
Any clue abount this? Or a different aproach?

Example: https://gist.github.com/daniel-frank/a88fa4553ed34c348528f51d33c3733b

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious. Maybe you can shared a stack trace on the matter to determine the point of the `StackOverflowException`?

Comment: Sure! Gist updated with full log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I see now. Let me simplify your recursive code to show the problem:

```
private IntegrationFlow getPageFlow() {
        return f -> f
                .publishSubscribeChannel(ps -> ps
                         .subscribe(this.nextPageFlow())
                );
    }


private IntegrationFlow nextPageFlow() {
        return f -> f
                .publishSubscribeChannel(ps -> ps
                        .subscribe(this.getPageFlow())
                );
}
```

So, technically we have this structure in the memory:

```
getPageFlow
    nextPageFlow
        getPageFlow
           nextPageFlow
               getPageFlow
```

and so on.

Another problem here that each `.subscribe(this.nextPageFlow())` creates a new instance of the `IntegrationFlow` meanwhile logically you expect only one.

I understand that you can't declare beans in the `IntegrationFlowAdapter` impl, but that won't have with the `StackOverflowException` anyway.

What I see as a problem in your approach is a lack of the `MessageChannel` abstraction.

You use `publishSubscribeChannel` everywhere, meanwhile you could just distinguish the logic by the explicit channel definition in your flow.

To break the recursion and keep the code as closer to your solution as possible I'd make like this:

```
 private IntegrationFlow getPageFlow() {
        return f -> f
                .channel("pageServiceChannel")
                .handle(Http
                          .outboundGateway("https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description={description}&page={page}")
 ...

   private IntegrationFlow nextPageFlow() {
        return f -> f
                .filter("!payload.isEmpty()")
                .enrichHeaders(e -> e.headerExpression("page", "headers.getOrDefault('page', 0) + 1", true))
                .channel("pageServiceChannel");
    }
```

Of course you still have a recursion, but that will be already at run time, logical.

Comment: I understand. Channels is first class citizens in Spring Integration, even so I normally prefer a more "type safe" approach connecting flows to flows (eg: subFlowMapping instead of channelMapping in routers). Thank you!

Comment: You still can keep "type safe" via methods which return channels. But I see what you mean. Unfortunately there is no ability to stop declaration recursion if we just call method from method and back.